# Debug info package for centos

Tags: linux, centos, gdb, debugger

Hi I am getting the following on each line of gdb instruction steps. Does anyone know what package I need to install to remove this message from a CentOS build?

Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64

CentOs version 6.5  Kernel build 2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: Try installing yum-utils package first.
then use "debuginfo-install libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64" Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389988/missing-separate-debuginfos-use-debuginfo-install-glibc-2-12-1-47-el6-2-9-i686

debuginfo-install libtool-ltdl should do.